# Scraping ASP pages with Excel/VBA

Tags: asp.net, excel, vba, query-string, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape an ASP.NET page with Excel. Unfortunately, the page only returns 50 records at a time, of several pages. Excel's native Web Query module only picks up the first page. I want all the pages.

Like most (all?) ASP pages, there are a few hidden variables sent back to the server when requesting a new page. The important ones are _VIEWSTATE and _EVENT_VALIDATION.

I've written a VBA function that gets the HTML source of the page and scrapes these variables from it.

I've also written an .iqy page, which allows for POST requests in it. It looks something like this:

```
WEB
1
http://www.myaspwebsite/search/search_List.aspx
__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTEy[....truncated ..50k characters..]Mhudyk5U6u8%2BBpvxDPN8R4%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWFQL%2FkN%2FBCgL6g%2B5vAvfY06EOAoic4qIIAome%2Bf4PAuOrjYgIAuKrjYgIAuGrjYgIAuCrjYgIAuerjYgIAt7e34UPAvuL7m8CtuLToQ4CiaTioggCyKX5%2Fg8C4tv1sAgC49v1sAgC4Nv1sAgC4dv1sAgC5tv1sAgC%2Fd7fhQ%2BU8QRtxd7MM4Bpa%2F%2FZC7I64eUh3Q%3D%3D&ctl00_RadMenu1_ClientState=&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24NavBar1%24PageNoDropDownList=2&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24NavBar1%24btnGo=Go&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24NavBar2%24PageNoDropDownList=1

Selection=AllTables
Formatting=None
PreFormattedTextToColumns=True
ConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne=True
SingleBlockTextImport=False
DisableDateRecognition=False
DisableRedirections=False
```

This iqy page successfully retuns the desired results if the post query is placed in the file.
I can also use this .iqy page programmatically in VBA and assign the POST query dynamically using QueryTables. However, I get told that my query returned nothing.
I suspect this is because of the length of my argument. The VIEWSTATE alone is about 50k characters. I've tried printing the argument string to a file and it truncates it. However, I can read the same string from a file and use it dynamically successfully.

My questions are : Am I going about this the best way? What limitations should I be aware of when doing this? Also, is there a limit to string size in Excel?

Comment: Are you saying you did a paramaterised POST request using querytables?

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft's documentation on Visual Basic [strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/string-data-type) (same value applies to VBA strings):

> A string can contain from 0 to approximately two billion (2 ^ 31) Unicode characters.

That is more than enough to handle a 50k string. A simple way to bypass IDE line limits and immediate window printing limits would be to print the string into an Excel cell and then read it back into a variable when you need to use that piece of data.